# What is the meaning of Avadhoota?

Tags: yoga

I came across these terminology,can someone tell me

Who is called an Avadhoota ?
What is the meaning of Avadhoota chintana ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word Avadhoota (अवधूत) has the following meanings

> shaken, waved
>
> discarded, rejected, despised
>
> insulted, humiliated
>
> excelled, surpassed
>
> attacked, overcome
>
> **separated from worldly attachments and connections** as referenced from these two Shlokas

1.

> यो विलंघ्याश्रमान्वर्णानातमन्येथ स्थितः पुमान् ।
>
> अतिवर्णाश्रमी योगी अवधूतः स उच्यते ॥

2.

> अक्षरत्वात् वरेण्यत्वान् धूतसंसारबंधनात ।
>
> तस्वमस्यर्थसिन्द्वतवादवधूतोऽभिधीयते ॥

The word Chintanam (चिंतनं) has the following meanings

> **thinking, thought**
>
> sad or sorrowful thought, care, anxiety
>
> **reflection, consideration**

***Hence, Avadhoota Chintanam means the contemplation of the one who is separated from worldly attachments and connections; or thinking about the Guru (enlightened Master)***

Reference used:  [The Practical Sanskrit-English Dictionary](https://archive.org/details/ldpd_7285627_000) by *Vaman Shivaram Apte.*